# missing row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT stat, 
           SUM(DECODE(visa_country,'US',1,0)) AS USA,
           SUM(DECODE(visa_country,'United Kingdom',1,0)) AS UK,
           SUM(DECODE(visa_country,'Australia',1,0)) AS Australia,
           SUM(DECODE(visa_country,'Canada',1,0)) AS Canada,
           SUM(DECODE(visa_country,'Switzerland',1,0)) AS Switzerland,
           SUM(DECODE(visa_country,'Singapore',1,0)) AS Singapore,
           SUM(DECODE(visa_country,'Sweden',1,0)) AS Sweden,
           SUM(DECODE(visa_country,'Netherlands',1,0)) AS Netherlands
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  stat,
                    visa_country,
                    DECODE(stat,'>= 0 '||'&'||' < 15', 1
                               ,'>= 15 '||'&'||' < 30',2
                               ,'>= 30 '||'&'||' < 45',3
                               ,'>= 45 '||'&'||' < 60',4
                               ,'>= 60 '||'&'||' < 75',5
                               ,'>= 75 '||'&'||' < 90',6
                               ,' >= 90',7) AS gr
            FROM (
                SELECT  end_date,
                        visa_country,
                        CASE WHEN END_DATE between 0 and 14 THEN '>= 0 '||'&'||' < 15'
                             WHEN END_DATE BETWEEN 15 AND 29 THEN '>= 15 '||'&'||' < 30'
                             WHEN END_DATE BETWEEN 30 AND 44 THEN '>= 30 '||'&'||' < 45'
                             WHEN END_DATE BETWEEN 45 AND 59 THEN '>= 45 '||'&'||' < 60'
                             WHEN END_DATE BETWEEN 60 AND 74 THEN '>= 60 '||'&'||' < 75'
                             WHEN END_DATE BETWEEN 75 AND 89 THEN '>= 75 '||'&'||' < 90'
                             WHEN END_DATE > 90 THEN  ' >= 90'   
                        END AS stat
                FROM 
                (
                    SELECT  visa_country,
                            GREATEST(
                                        NVL(TO_DATE(VP.WP_VALID_TILL,'DD-MON-YY'),TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YY')),
                                        NVL(TO_DATE(VP.VISA_VALID_TILL,'DD-MON-YY'),to_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YY'))
                                    )
                            - TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YY') AS END_DATE 
                    FROM visa_prac AS vp 
                )
            ) AS x
            WHERE x.end_date > 0
        )       
    )  GROUP BY stat
    ORDER BY gr
)
```

This is the code which gives the count of the employees ... But the problem here is that if any count is zero it is not showing that entire row....

Supppose no details falls in the range of >=75 & <90 then that row is not showing up..

Will be grateful for your kind help resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the `WHERE` clause in the END

`WHERE x.end_date >0`

Because it is filtering out the rows in case of ZERO.

```
select * from 
  (
      select stat, sum(decode(visa_country,'US',1,0))USA,
             sum(decode(visa_country,'United Kingdom',1,0))UK,
             sum(decode(visa_country,'Australia',1,0))Australia,
             sum(decode(visa_country,'Canada',1,0)) Canada,
             sum(decode(visa_country,'Switzerland',1,0))Switzerland,
             sum(decode(visa_country,'Singapore',1,0))Singapore,
             sum(decode(visa_country,'Sweden',1,0))Sweden,
             sum(decode(visa_country,'Netherlands',1,0))Netherlands
      from 
            (
            select * FROM
                (
                  SELECT stat,visa_country,DECODE(stat,'>= 0 '||'&'||' < 15',1,'>= 15 '||'&'||' < 30',2,'>= 30 '||'&'||' < 45',3,'>= 45 '||'&'||' < 60',4,'>= 60 '||'&'||' < 75' ,5,'>= 75 '||'&'||' < 90' ,6,' >= 90',7)gr
                    from (
                            select end_date,visa_country,case when END_DATE between 0 and 14 THEN '>= 0 '||'&'||' < 15'
                              when END_DATE BETWEEN 15 AND 29 THEN '>= 15 '||'&'||' < 30'
                              When END_DATE BETWEEN 30 AND 44 THEN '>= 30 '||'&'||' < 45'
                              When END_DATE BETWEEN 45 AND 59 THEN '>= 45 '||'&'||' < 60'
                              When END_DATE BETWEEN 60 AND 74 THEN '>= 60 '||'&'||' < 75'
                              When END_DATE BETWEEN 75 AND 89 THEN '>= 75 '||'&'||' < 90'
                              When END_DATE > 90 THEN  ' >= 90'   
                                 END stat
                          from (select visa_country,GREATEST(nvl(TO_DATE(VP.WP_VALID_TILL,'DD-MON-YY'),to_DATE(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY')),NVL(TO_DATE(VP.VISA_VALID_TILL,'DD-MON-YY'),to_DATE(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY')))
                          -to_DATE(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY') AS END_DATE from visa_prac vp )

                          )x 
                )   
            )  group by stat
            order by gr
  )
```

Comment: hi talha.i think d problem s with one part f the code which i m mentioning below.hope u understand the logic f d entire code.i know its clumsy and i am very new to this.plz suggest some alternative for this....select visa_country,GREATEST(nvl(TO_DATE(VP.WP_VALID_TILL,'DD-MON-YY'),to_DATE(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY')),NVL(TO_DATE(VP.VISA_VALID_TILL,'DD-MON-YY'),to_DATE(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY'))) -to_DATE(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY') AS END_DATE from visa_prac vp....i this i am trying to eliminate the date which is less than sysdate.i am making it zero.so if i miss "WHERE x.end_date >0" it gives old records too

Comment: OK So you could try it with: `WHERE x.end_date >= 0` This will include the all the rows with ZEROS as well.

Comment: no it doesnt seems to be working...... :-( i tried it but still the row is missing.particularly 75 to 90 since there is no data in all the columns in that row

Comment: >= 0 & < 15  1 2 0 0 1 0 0 0    >= 15 & < 30  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0      >= 30 & < 45 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0    >= 45 & < 60  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0     >= 60 & < 75 2 0 0 0 1 0 1 0    >= 90       96  8 6 3 1 1 2 3  this is the output..as u can see 75 to 90 is missing

Comment: I think you have to make another table with the 7 records of ranges `>=0 & <15, >=15 & < 30, .... , >= 90` and Make an `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and select the range from the new table and the values from the current implementation.